# C# Post-Request Status 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, post, httprequest

I am currently working on a C# Programm that is supposed to get Data from a REST API that I host.

The API requires a token for authentication which is returned from a POST request.

When I try to do the POST with C# I get a bad request (Status 400) but the GET request works fine. Now, My question is what I did wrong or what might be the cause for that error. When doing the request with postman both work perfectly.

The POST function:

```
void POST(string url, string jsonContent) {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";

        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = @"application/json";

        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
        long length = 0;
        try {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
                length = response.ContentLength;
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }
        } catch (WebException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

The GET function:

```
string GET(string url) {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        } catch (WebException ex) {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // log errorText
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it depends on what you are posting, what is expected input from the server you are posting

Comment: Does  the BadRequest have any other indication what is missing? Most likely should have some validation rules as the payload you are sending doesn't satisfy all the params it needs

Comment: @Justcode The data that is required is a json with two values: username and password

Comment: @npo It only says that the remote Server has thrown an Error

I tried to log the request on Serversite but the function to handle the input doesn't even get called so I guess the request must be rejected before that

Comment: @Nautha first check with postman is request is going or not.

Comment: @Justcode yes with postman everything is working

Comment: This sounds like a deserialization issue.  Without seeing the data you post and the signature of the post handler we can't really help other than *"make sure they match"*.

Comment: @Nautha what is you are getting in `jsonContent`?

Comment: @Justcode the output of the JsonConvert.SerializeObject() function of NewtonsoftJson NuGet. Or in other words a json String:
{ "username":"test", "password:"123"}

Comment: Seems to be a valid request, can you post screenshot of error?

Comment: Can you post the controller method that is meant to take the POST request?  The 400 error means that it can't match your JSON with a request handler, which is why it never steps into the handler (it's not executed).

Comment: Is there a way to get a json from the exception? The Server sends details on how the error occured.

Comment: @Nautha I've explained what's wrong with it, but we can't help you unless you post the signature of the POST handler.  It's failing when attempting to match what you send with a handler's type & parameters.